# React Native Background Timer perform action after x time

Tags: reactjs, react-native, timer, background, task

I would like to create dismiss button that stops currently playing song and plays it after specified amount of time (let's say 5 minutes) What should I do? Here is my code:

```
  onPressButtonPlay() {
    if(song != null) {
        song.play((success) => {
            if(!success)
                ToastAndroid.show('Error when play SoundPlayer :(((', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        });
    }   
  }


onPressButtonDismiss() {
    if(song != null) {
        song.stop((success) => {
            if(!success)
                ToastAndroid.show('Alarm dismissed', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        });
    }   
  }

  onPressButtonStop() {
    if(song != null) {
        song.stop((success) => {
            if(!success)
                ToastAndroid.show('Alarm stopped', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        });
    }   
  }  

  componentDidMount() {
   this.timeoutCheck = setTimeout(() => {
   this.setTimePassed();
   }, 400);
  }

  setTimePassed() {
   this.setState({timePassed: true});
  }

  onPressButtonTimer() {
  if (!this.state.timePassed){
      song.play();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you using redux at all?

Comment: Yes. All modules work fine, just don't know how to write correct code.

Comment: Can I suggest adding redux-saga and handling the timer there? They have a nice delay function where you can wait for the delay then move forward after the time has elapsed and call the next function.

Comment: Isn't that possible to do that with background-timer? If no how should my code look like while using redux-saga?

Comment: I have never used background-timer, that looks like an interesting solution. I think that might fit how you are building this better than the redux architecture I have been using on my app.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem! Here are the steps:

At first create function thet will play alarm/music after specified amount of time (one second in this case):

```
var SoundPlayer = require('react-native-sound');

var song = null;

export default class App extends Component<{}> {

  PlaySongWithDelay=()=>{

    setTimeout(function(){

      //Put All Your Code Here, Which You Want To Execute After Some Delay Time.
      song.play()

    }, 1000);


  }

  componentWillMount() {
    song = new SoundPlayer('daydream.mp3', SoundPlayer.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => {
      if(error)
        ToastAndroid.show('Error when init SoundPlayer :(((', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    });
  }
```

After that create buttons. Here is the code for button that plays song from above and the one that stops it:

```
  onPressButtonPlay() {
  if(song != null) {
    song.play((success) => {
      if(!success)
        ToastAndroid.show('Error when play SoundPlayer :(((', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    });
  } 
  }

  onPressButtonDismiss() {
  if(song != null) {
    song.stop((success) => {
      if(!success)
        ToastAndroid.show('Alarm dismissed', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    });
  } 
  }
```

And here is the function that binds two actions (stop and play after x time) to create double action button.

```
  onPressButtonStopAndDismiss(){
    this.onPressButtonDismiss();
    this.PlaySongWithDelay();
```

Finally code to render our buttons:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPressButtonPlay.bind(this)}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Play</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>

         <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPressButtonStopAndDismiss.bind(this)}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Dismiss</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

I hope it will be helpful ;)

NOTE: Save your sound clip files under the directory `android/app/src/main/res/raw`

Comment: I couldn't achieve it to make sleeper timer in my react native app.

If user sets 30 mins , then app should stop the music playing in the background after 30 mins.

It worked from me in ios but not in android. :(